# Toggling images with javascript. My code works until I loop a php variable in the function. Can I do this?

Tags: javascript, php, togglebutton, toggleclass

I am trying to toggle between 2 button images for 2 elements. When I click 1 element I want to change the background image to make the button appear indented, but when I click the 2nd element I want the 1st to change back to how it originally was and change the 2nd element's image.

I found some JavaScript that almost did what I want, and I modified it to meet my needs and it worked perfectly in my test page, but when I put it into my actual site it behaves differently.

On my live page I have a database and I use PHP to loop 10 entries with these buttons.. When I click 1 element it changes as intended, but when I click the other element the first does not change back, and both elements are stuck on the 2nd image.

It seems like JavaScript doesn't like variables that are being looped with different values. I've messed around for hours trying to figure out the problem but I am at a loss. Here is the code in question

```
<?  $grabvalue = $row['id']; ?>
    <script>
function toggleClass(el){
    var kids = document.getElementById('buttons<?php echo $grabvalue; ?>').children;

kids[0].className = "button1";
kids[1].className = "button2";

    if (el.className == "button1"){ 
    el.className = "button1_down";

    }
    if (el.className == "button2"){
    el.className = "button2_down";
    }
}
 </script>   

    <span class='buttons' id='buttons<?php echo $grabvalue; ?>'>

    <a href='#' class='button1' onClick='toggleClass(this)' id='button1'></a>
        <a href='#' class='button2' onClick='toggleClass(this)' id='button2'></a>
    </span>
```

I'm sure there's problems in this code, but it works. The problem starts when I start to loop the php array $row. When I do, both buttons work, and change images when I click on them, but they get stuck on the button1_down and button2_down images. If I don't loop  $row and let it be static with 1 value it works as intended for the entry with that value. What is the problem ? How do I accomplish this?

Comment: Is `$grabvalue = $row['id']` placed just like that in your code? if so, then there's a error.

Comment: If this whole section of code is in your loop then you're assigning the same button1 and button2 ids to all of the hyperlinks.

Comment: Also, if this whole section of code is in a loop, then you're defining the function toggleClass each time you iterate the loop.

Comment: How do I use this code in a loop for the information from my database?

Comment: I got the result I wanted by creating a loop of new functions for every single element. Surely there's a better way to do this right?